Compostitum is Galois and isomorphism of Galois groups
Question: Let $K, L, F$ be subfields of a field $\Omega$, and suppose that $K \subset L$ is Galois and that $K \subset F$. Prove that $F \subset LF$ is Galois and that $\text{Gal}(LF/F) \cong \text{Gal}(L/L \cap F)$ as topological groups.
Own attempts: This question has appeared on the site before but it often only deals the case where the extensions are finite.
To prove that $F \subset LF$ is Galois, note that $K \subset L$ is Galois and hence $L = \bigcup_{E \in I} E$ where $E/K$ are finite Galois. Now consider the set $J = \{EF \mid F \subset EF \subset LF, E \in I\}$. Then it follows that $EF/F$ is finite Galois for all $E \in I$ and $\bigcup_{EF \in J} EF = LF$. Hence $LF / F$ is also Galois.
Then considering the isomorphism, I was wondering if the proof is analogues to the finite case, of which I know the proof. This is done by considering the map
$\phi : \text{Gal}(LF/F) \rightarrow \text{Gal}(L/L \cap F) : \sigma \mapsto \sigma\mid_{L}$.
So I am wondering if my reasoning of showing that $LF/F$ is Galois is correct, and whether I can still use the map $\phi$ to show that there is an isomorphism in the infinite case. Thanks in advance.

Looks correct so far.  Your map $\phi$ is injective and continuous, and the Galois groups are compact Hausdorff, so $\phi$ is a closed embedding. You just have to show then that $\phi$ is surjective, whose proof is analogous to the finite case.

Thank you for your comment @kobe. I have one question, I am new to infinite Galois theory and often I am struggling to prove that a map is continuous. Could you please demonstrate how I could show that here? (i.e. what are really the open sets in the Galois groups?). Thanks in advance.

If $M|F$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$, the collection $${ \operatorname{Gal}(M|K): \text{$K|F$ is a finite Galois subextension of $M|F$}}$$ is a base of neighborhoods of $1$ in $G$. Now let $N|L\cap F$ be a finite Galois subextension of $L|L\cap F$. Can you find a basic open neighborhood $B$ of $1$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(LF|F)$ such that $\phi(B) \subset \operatorname{Gal}(L|N)$?

Thanks again for your comment @kobe. Would the basic open neighbourhood of $\text{Gal}(LF/F)$ be the group $B = \text{Gal}(LF/N)$ such that $\phi(B) \subset \text{Gal}(L/N)$? Also, is the main idea here that we take a basis element in $\text{Gal}(LF/F)$ and show that its image is contained in a basis element of $\text{Gal}(L/L\cap F)$, so that we can conclude that $\phi$ is indeed continuous?

For simplicity, let $G = \operatorname{Gal}(LF|F)$ and $H = \operatorname{Gal}(L|L\cap F)$. Since $G$ and $H$ are topological groups and $\phi : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, to show $\phi$ is continuous, it suffices to show continuity of $\phi$ at the identity $1$ of $\operatorname{Gal}(LF|F)$. Take a basic open $U$ of $\phi(1) = 1$ in $H$, and find a basic open $B \ni 1$ in $G$ such that $\phi(B) \subset U$.

Okay I understand why that applies here now. Then could I consider $\text{Gal}(LF/NF)$? After restricting to $L$ it is an automorphism from $L$ to $L$ that is the identity on $NF$, and hence on $N$ in particular. Thus the image is contained in $\text{Gal}(L/N)$. However, how would I see that $NF/F$ is finite Galois?

Correct. Now observe that since $N|L\cap F$ is finite Galois, it is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(x) \in (L\cap F)[x]$. The polynomial is still separable in $F[x]$ and $NF|F$ is the splitting field of $f(x) \in F[x]$. Therefore $NF|F$ is finite Galois.
